# post clickable link on Facebook -- with Send button or Send dialog?

Tags: facebook

We need to allow the user of our site to post a clickable link to Facebook.  More precisely --
we need to pre-fill one of the Facebook plug-ins with a clickable link on behalf of the user.
We cannot rely on the user to type in this link themselves.

We researched this and the Share functionality seemed to offer that but FB has deprecated Share:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/

We successfully implemented the Send button (see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/)

The Send button though does not allow us to post a clickable link.  While the user of our site
can click 'Send' on our site, and the Send dialog then pops up  -- we cannot 'pre-fill' the Send dialog box
with a click-able link.

Is there a way to post a clickable link to Facebook (other than the now-deprecated Share) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea,

Instead, why wouldn't you implement send message using [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/)

Some thing like [this(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/gftXF/)

Hope this is helps

Comment: DONE.  We are there.  The send button just is not enough -- your fiddle has a clickable link which is what we need -- thanks -- now off to code it.